# Android cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java, android, static-methods

I'm a beginner on Android and this is the first I'm creating an app named GeoQuiz which basically has a few questions and the user has to click true/false or request the answer with the cheat button.I'm getting this one line of error related with a non-static an a static context in line 138,what am I doing wrong? I'm trying that every time i click on the button cheat, it open the other window that is under a different .xml file and in an another java class

```
package com.example.fusion.geoquiz;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.Intent;
import java.util.*;
import static com.example.fusion.geoquiz.R.string.correct_toast;

public class QuizActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private Button mTrueButton;
    private Button mFalseButton;
    private ImageButton mNextButton;
    private ImageButton mPrevButton;
    private ProgressBar mProgress;
    private Button mCheatButton;
    private int mProgressStatus = 0;
    private TextView mQuestionTextView;
    private static final String TAG = "QuizActivity";
    private static final String KEY_INDEX = "index";
    private int checker = 0;

    private TrueFalse[] mQuestionBank = new TrueFalse[] {
            new TrueFalse(R.string.question_oceans, true),
            new TrueFalse(R.string.question_mideast, false),
            new TrueFalse(R.string.question_africa, false),
            new TrueFalse(R.string.question_americas, true),
            new TrueFalse(R.string.question_asia, true),
    };
    private int mCurrentIndex = 0;
    private void disablePrev(){
        if(mCurrentIndex== 0){
            mPrevButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.prev_button);
            mPrevButton.setEnabled(false);
        }
        else{
            mPrevButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.prev_button);
            mPrevButton.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }
    private void updateQuestion() {
        int question = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].getQuestion();
        mQuestionTextView.setText(question);
    }
    private void checkAnswer(boolean userPressedTrue) {
        boolean answerIsTrue = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].isTrueQuestion();
        int messageResId = 0;
        if (userPressedTrue == answerIsTrue) {
            messageResId = R.string.correct_toast;
            checker++;

            if(checker >0) {
                mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex + 1) % mQuestionBank.length;
                updateQuestion();
                //mProgressStatus=checker;
                //mProgress.setProgress(mProgressStatus);
                disablePrev();
            }
        } else {
            messageResId = R.string.incorrect_toast;
            checker = 0;
        }
        Toast.makeText(this, messageResId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);
        disablePrev();
        mQuestionTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.question_text_view);
        updateQuestion();
        mTrueButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.true_button);
        mTrueButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){

                checkAnswer(false);
            }
        });

        mFalseButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.false_button);
        mFalseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
               checkAnswer(true);
            }
        });
            mNextButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.next_button);
            mNextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(checker==1) {
                        mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex + 1) % mQuestionBank.length;
                        updateQuestion();
                        disablePrev();
                    }
                }
            });

            mPrevButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.prev_button);
            disablePrev();
        mPrevButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mCurrentIndex != 0){
                    mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex - 1) % mQuestionBank.length;
                    updateQuestion();
                    disablePrev();
                 }
            }
        });
        mQuestionTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(checker==1) {
                    mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex + 1) % mQuestionBank.length;
                    updateQuestion();
                    disablePrev();
                }
            }
        });
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mCurrentIndex = savedInstanceState.getInt(KEY_INDEX, 0);
        }
        mCheatButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cheat_button);
        mCheatButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(QuizActivity.this, cheatActivity.startActivity(intent));
            }
        });
        disablePrev();
        updateQuestion();
    }
    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        Log.i(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState");
        savedInstanceState.putInt(KEY_INDEX, mCurrentIndex);
    }
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.d(TAG, "onStart() called");
    }
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.d(TAG, "onPause() called");
    }
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.d(TAG, "onResume() called");
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_quiz, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

this is the class for the cheat class and cheatButton

```
package com.example.fusion.geoquiz;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.util.Log;
/**
 * Created by fusion on 1/21/2015.
 */
public class cheatActivity extends Activity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cheat);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the line 138??

Comment: what is line 138?? and in which file???

Comment: I would strongly and I mean seriously recommend you to read at least one good book of android and one good book of Java if you want to go down this way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
Intent intent = new Intent(QuizActivity.this, cheatActivity.startActivity(intent));
```

with

```
Intent intent = new Intent(QuizActivity.this, cheatActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

See the [docs](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html) for more details..

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're doing there, but you need to reference the other activity class. Simply calling `startActivity` is enough, because it will be implicitly called from `QuizActivity.this`.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(QuizActivity.this, cheatActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

---

To save you from future errors choose one activity class that you will be using either `Activity` or `ActionBarActivity`. The latter is from the support package.